# Alternative to Thunar that can access Android fs (Samsung Galaxy Tab S SM-T700) via USB

Tags: usb, filesystem, android, samsung

I've spent one frustrating hour trying in vain to get Thunar to access the files ystem of a Samsung Galaxy Tab S SM-T700 via USB.  I'm now fed up with Thunar<sup>1</sup>, and I'm ready to give it the ol' heave-ho.

Rather than blindly trying alternative file managers until one works, I'm looking for recommendations of file managers that are known to being able of accessing (via USB) the file system of the Android device described hardware.

FWIW, my desktop manager is xfce4.

EDIT: OK, I tried PCManFM.  At least it shows an entry labeled `SAMSUNG Android` among the mounted volumes, but when I visit this volume, it appears to be empty, even though the tablet's file manager shows a ton of files, mostly under `Documents` and `Download`.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I particularly dislike the absence of any solid authoritative documentation on how to do what I'm trying to do</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `gigolo` to mount the device.

or

You can try to use mtp type:

```
fusermount -u /media/mtpdevice/ 
mount | grep mtpfs
```